# Strong Parameters in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

[This video](http://vimeo.com/51181496) states that it is possible to protect the input coming in via the controller yet still be able to do mass assignment via models and specs.  However, I have not seen this documented as a feature when using strong_parameters in 3.2.8.

I understand that I need to mix in `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` into my models and set `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` in `config/application.rb`.  I have also pulled all of my `attr_accessible` calls from the model.

With or without the mixin I am getting mass assignment errors.

`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: home_phone, cell_phone`

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you do `attr_protected :home_phone, :cell_phone` they won't be able to mass assigned.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have `attr_protected` in my model either. But I am getting that same error.

Comment: @brandon-hansen - have you watched Ryan Bates' railscast on this subject? http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters?view=asciicast

Comment: could you add the stack trace?

Comment: Maybe some other gem/code in lib folder causing a problem (eg something that extends activerecord)? If you create a fresh Rails app and try strong parameters, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Maybe you have some module mixed which used attr_accessible/etc. calls

Answer (score 23):

The suggested [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters?view=asciicast) is probably a good start, but here is a summary of what you have to do in Rails 3.x to get strong parameters working instead of attr_accessible:

1. Add `gem 'strong_parameters'` to your Gemfile and run bundle.
2. Comment out (or set to false) `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in config/application.rb
3. Mix in the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` in your model. Do this per model, or apply globally to all models with:

   `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include,  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)`

   (The railscast proposes to do this in a new initializer:  config/initializers/strong_parameters.rb )
4. From now on you will have to use syntax such as this:

   ```
   model_params = params[:model].permit( :attribute, :another_attribute )
   @model.update_attributes( model_params )
   ```

   when you update your models. In this case any attribute in `params[:model]` except `:attribute` and `:another_attribute` will cause an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes error.

You can also use the rest of the new magic from `ActionController::Parameters`, such as `.require(:attribute)` to force the presence of an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the same as your issue but it may come up for someone else getting MassAssignmentSecurity::Error. I've hit an issue that 'id' and 'type' attributes seem to be protected by default even when I had taken the prescribed steps to switch to using strong parameters rather than mass assignment protection.  I had an association named 'type' which I renamed to 'project_type' to resolve the problem (the attribute was already project_type_id).

Comment: Using `type` for attributes or relations is a bad idea since Rails uses that to keep track of STI relations. So it's more or less a reserved attribute :) Also `id` is the default param that gets set in a number of cases by the router so that might be precarious to use as well.

Comment: @d-Pixie Fair enough but the errors I got were really not helpful and very confusing.  An error saying not to use those would be fine, an MassAssignmentSecurity::Error when that whole system was meant to be disabled was very confusing. type was the one that I hit and I found id was also affected when I dug into the sourcecode.

Comment: Ran in to the same problem, error is not descriptive. Use `self.inheritance_column = nil` to fix if you're not using STI.