# strong parameters Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.2.14, inherited_resource and strong_parameter gem.I just followed [Strong Parameters in Rails 3.2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852534/strong-parameters-in-rails-3-2-8) steps but i am getting error like below,

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes:content, title, nature_bien_id, nature_transaction_id, nbr_chambres, nbr_pieces, section_id, city, zip, surface_habitable, surface_terrain
```

My code in controller is like that

```
def create
    @mandat = current_user.mandats.new(mandats_params)
end
private
def annonce_params
  params.require(:annonce).permit(:created_at, :description, :image, :dpe, :nature_bien_id, :nature_transaction_id,:nbr_chambres, :nbr_pieces, :prix_net_acquereur, :section_id, :surface_habitable,:surface_terrain, :titre, :annonce_images_attributes, :user_id, :ville, :zip, :reference,:available_time, :is_valid, :close, :reasonclosing, :annonce_support_ids, :equipement_ids)
end
```

Thanks for in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my rails project,I use audited Gem.Refer [Audited gem using strong Parameter](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#using-attr_protected-or-strong_parameters).So in my model

Change

```
class Mandat < ActiveRecord::Base
    audited on: [:update]
```

to

```
class Mandat < ActiveRecord::Base
    audited :allow_mass_assignment => true,on: [:update]
```

then it will works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off attributes protection in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that all attributes that you want to updated are listed in the `attr_accessible` definition in your `Mandat` model:

```
attr_accessible :created_at, :description, :image, :dpe, :nature_bien_id, 
  :nature_transaction_id,:nbr_chambres, :nbr_pieces, :prix_net_acquereur, 
  :section_id, :surface_habitable,:surface_terrain, :titre, 
  :annonce_images_attributes, :user_id, :ville, :zip, :reference,
  :available_time, :is_valid, :close, :reasonclosing, :annonce_support_ids, 
  :equipement_ids
```

Comment: @Balachandran: I am sorry, you need to use `attr_accessible`, not `attr_protected`.

Comment: I forget to say audited gem use in that model.I found that solution and solve my issue.Thanks